# Optimizing an old code for choosing rating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this ugly old code that is doing a pretty good work, but I need to somehow optimize it. Code's purpose is to define what background to set on each star (1-5) based on what user checked (radio inputs). The example goal is if the user selected 3 stars (from 1 to 5) the first 3 (including the third star) stars should be with different colors based on the stars user chose. Hopefully you understand what I'm talking about, either look at the code so you can understand more deeply:

HTML

```
<span class="rating">
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="5_star" name="review_stars" value="5" autocomplete="off" required><label for="5_star" class="rating-star5"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="4_star" name="review_stars" value="4" autocomplete="off" required><label for="4_star" class="rating-star4"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="3_star" name="review_stars" value="3" autocomplete="off" required><label for="3_star" class="rating-star3"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="2_star" name="review_stars" value="2" autocomplete="off" required><label for="2_star" class="rating-star2"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="1_star" name="review_stars" value="1" autocomplete="off" required><label for="1_star" class="rating-star1"></label>
</span>
```

JS

```
$(".rating-star5").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars5.svg')");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if ($("#5_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars5.svg')");
            } else if ($("#4_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars4.svg')");
            } else if ($("#3_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars3.svg')");
            } else if ($("#2_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars2.svg')");
            } else if ($("#1_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars1.svg')");
            } else {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".rating-star4").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".rating-star5").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            $(".rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars4.svg')");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if ($("#5_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars5.svg')");
            } else if ($("#4_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars4.svg')");
            } else if ($("#3_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars3.svg')");
            } else if ($("#2_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars2.svg')");
            } else if ($("#1_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars1.svg')");
            } else {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".rating-star3").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            $(".rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars3.svg')");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if ($("#5_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars5.svg')");
            } else if ($("#4_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars4.svg')");
            } else if ($("#3_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars3.svg')");
            } else if ($("#2_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars2.svg')");
            } else if ($("#1_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars1.svg')");
            } else {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".rating-star2").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            $(".rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars2.svg')");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if ($("#5_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars5.svg')");
            } else if ($("#4_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars4.svg')");
            } else if ($("#3_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars3.svg')");
            } else if ($("#2_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars2.svg')");
            } else if ($("#1_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars1.svg')");
            } else {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".rating-star1").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            $(".rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars1.svg')");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if ($("#5_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars5.svg')");
            } else if ($("#4_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars4.svg')");
            } else if ($("#3_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars3.svg')");
            } else if ($("#2_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars2.svg')");
            } else if ($("#1_star").is(":checked")) {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
                $(".rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars1.svg')");
            } else {
                $(".rating-star5, .rating-star4, .rating-star3, .rating-star2, .rating-star1").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')");
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I optimize this code?

"Just because something can be done in some way doesn't mean it's the right way to do it" - That's absolutely true in this case.

Comment: you can use one event handler for all radio input and based on its value you can loop through prev and next radios to change their classes, if you provide css codes ill show you

Comment: theres is many example out there you can search it like this one: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-star-rating/

Comment: Not your exact code, but this question asks the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436313/best-way-to-add-add-new-class-when-the-i-tag-clicked-inside-div#comment124509690_70436313

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah, but my case is slightly different. If there are 4 stars selected, all the 4 stars are different color compared to for example 5, 3, 2, 1... Or if there are 3 stars selected, all the 3 stars are differently colored than if selected 5, 4, 2, 1.. etc...

Comment: Yeah, that's not my case. They are all the same color no matter how many stars you've selected.

Comment: Re-read what you said - you appear to have different coloured stars based on which was selected - add that as a data- attribute to each star and make it data-driven code.  To match your html/requirements: `$(".rating-input").css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/stars.svg')"); 
$(this).prevAll().add(this).css("background-image", $(this).data("url")); ;`

Comment: You could also do all of this with css and not have an js...